# add function to keep div.pop-up on hover

Tags: jquery

Pop to stay after hover and close when or close on mouse move right side........

```
          $(document).ready(function() {
            //If Javascript is running, change css on product-description to display:block
            //then hide the div, ready to animate
            $("div.pop-up").css({'display':'block','opacity':'0'})

            $("a.trigger").hover(
              function () {
                $(this).prev().stop().animate({
                  opacity: 1
                }, 500);
              },
              function () {
                $(this).prev().stop().animate({
                  opacity: 0
                }, 200);
              }
            )
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but this is how I translated it...

**Q:** How do I make the pop-up stay open when it's hovered over instead of closing because the trigger is no longer hovered over?

**A:** Are you able to change the mark-up at all?  If so, you can place the pop-up within the trigger element, that way when the pop-up is hovered over you haven't left the trigger:

`​     <div class="trigger">
         <a>Hover over me</a>
         <div class="pop-up">
             This is the pop-up, hover over me as well.
         </div>
     </div>​`

Then you just need to modify your Javascript slightly:

```
$("div.pop-up").css({
    'display': 'block',
    'opacity': '0'
});
$("div.trigger").hover(
function() {
    $(this).find("div.pop-up").stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).find("div.pop-up").stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 200);
});​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2kjVh/)